# How to read PDF files on Nokia Mobile phone?

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader, mobile-phone

I tried to read PDF files on `Nokia 6680` and install "`Adobe Reader LE v1.0`" but it always get "`Operation failed`" error and give this message

> `"Not enough memory".`

### Is there a better program to read PDF on Nokia 6680 ?

**Or it's not possible ?.**
.

*Thankx.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe Reader LE 2.5 solves the problem with opening large PDF files.

http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readerforsymbian.html

Comment: It says it can open large files **faster**, he can't open them at all.

Comment: I'll try this program but can't find suitable release that work on 6680

Comment: @ John: the upgrade solved all my PDF woes on a N90 (which has has more executable memory alright, 32 as opposed to 10), @ Wahid Bitar: if you have v1.0 for Symbian phones, then 2.5 should work just as well

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of the PDF? It's possible that it's too large to load into your remaining memory. If you have an adequate amount of memory installed, try freeing up some space by moving pictures and other data to your desktop for example, then open the PDF.

Comment: I freed memory and my PDF just 2.5 MB but can't read it